# Checking if subset is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a linear algebra question that caused lots of confusion for me.

Given that $W=\left\{\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{smallmatrix}\right]\in\Bbb R^4~:~a-2b=c~\text{and}~a+b+c=d\right\}$, is $W$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4?$

I am not sure at all how to approach this problem. I thought that substituting $c$ and $d$ into $W$ in terms of the other variables could lead to something, however, I could not get anywhere after doing so.

Comment: Your notation seems off.  Do you mean to say that $W=\left\{\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{smallmatrix}\right]\in\Bbb R^4~:~a-2b=c~\wedge~a+b+c=d\right\}$ and you ask if $W$ is a sub**space** of $\Bbb R^4$?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: Ask yourself if any linear combination of vectors in $W$ will again satisfy the properties of being in $W$.  That is to say, suppose $(a_1,b_1,c_1,d_1)$ and $(a_2,b_2,c_2,d_2)$ are both elements of $W$.  Ask yourself if $\alpha (a_1,b_1,c_1,d_1)+\beta (a_2,b_2,c_2,d_2)$ also satisfies the properties of being in $W$.  Worded a different (*longer and more tedious way*) check that $(0,0,0,0)\in W$, check that if $(a,b,c,d)\in W$ that this implies that $\alpha(a,b,c,d)\in W$, and check that if $(a,b,c,d)$ and $(a_2,b_2,c_2,d_2)\in W$ that $(a,b,c,d)+(a_2,b_2,c_2,d_2)$ is too.

Comment: You could take a shortcut and use what you know about spans of vectors and that a span of vectors is necessarily a subspace and note that your conditions can be rephrased that $c=a-2b$ and $d=2a-b$ so your set can be written as the span of two vectors (*which I leave to you to figure out what they are*).  If you are having difficulty with the proof technique I mention in my previous comment, check out any of the thousands of similar questions on this site for examples, starting your search with the "Related" bar on the right.

Comment: Your title indicates a misconception - a "vector" is not a subspace.

Comment: $W$ is the set of solutions of a system of homogeneous linear equations, and therefore it is a subspace. Easiest way to show this is to note that there is a matrix $A$ such that $W$ is the set of all solutions of $Ax=0$, and then use standard facts about matrix multiplication to establish the subspace properties.

Comment: Making any progress, stacko?